# Reading parameter in PHP from YAML to handle routing in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml

I have a PHP file which handles routes in a Symfony2 project and it works well, however, now I am trying to add a parameter to send it from app/config/routing.yaml to my php file

```
#app/config/routing.yaml
app:
    host:     "{ _locale }.*"
    defaults: { _locale: es}
    resource: "@AppBundle/config/routing.php"
    type:     php
    requirements: { _locale: en|es }

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

My doubt is how can I read _locale from the php routing file. I tried with           `$req= new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(); $req->getLocale()` but it always returns the same

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a new instance of Request. You need Request instance created by Symfony2 itself.

```
public function anyAction(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->getLocale();
}
```

Or you can try controller action argument.

```
public function anyAction($_locale)
{
}
```

You have also mistake in your requirements - `requirements: {_locale: en|es }` instead `requirements: {locale: en|es }`.

Comment: I see, I know I need to access to the Request instance created by Symfony2 but the problem is that I am trying to access from a routing file which is not a class

Comment: Why do you need it in routing file? I don't think it is even possible. You can take it from $_SERVER variable but you are trying to do some logic in simple route definition. If you will clarify what you want, then someone can help you.